# Is there MouseUp event for a worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have a userform with Treeview control on it and I'm dragging nodes from that control and drop 'em onto a worksheet. This part works fine but I need to know cell address (or at least row number) where user dropped the node. I was hoping to find something like MouseUp event and hittest function but apparently Excel doesn't provide with this functionality.

Of course, it's possible to check Worksheet_SelectionChange which occurs shortly after _OLECompleteDrag but it doesn't appeal to me as a "sure way".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code in the sheet module (in the directory Microsoft Excel Objects when looking at the Project Explorer of VBA), not in its own separate module in the Modules directory. Essentially, you need an event handler that triggers the process you want.

This will do the triggering and will show the cell's address when triggered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox (Target.Address)

End Sub
```

You should be able to expand on that to make it do what you need. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: I was talking about the same thing, the worksheet change event combined with timer (event should occur shortly after OLECompleteDrag. I have implemented that and it works but I was looking for a better solution.